# Eclipse ADT plugin version 16.0.0, where is it?

Tags: android, adt

I've just checked the developers' site homepage to find that there is now a version 16 of the SDK tools and a matching version 16.0.0 of the ADT Eclipse plugin available. I've installed the SDK tools OK but Eclipse's check for updates doesn't show a version 16 available for the plugin.

The [download site](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) shows 15 as the latest, which I've already got.

Has anyone successfully installed version 16 of the plugin?

I'd rather install it from the site than use the zip (which is available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 16 is now available via the Eclipse/'check for updates' route as normal.

Answer (score 2):

ADT 16 isn't final yet, though you can download a preview *(= beta)* version via that zip-file.
That's the reason why the updater won't find it, it will when this version is finally released. So if you want ADT 16 now, you have to use the zip.

See the first few paragraphs on the [tools site](http://tools.android.com/download).

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's useful to know that the zip is a preview. I'll stick with 15 until it becomes final. They don't usually list preview zips as 'available' on the home page, that's what threw me.

Comment: Oh right, just checked. That's indeed weird. Seems like the eclipse plugin lags behind. Oh the other hand I don't see a "ADT 16 released" post. Somethings off here, maybe a mistake on googles part.

Comment: I've just checked the SDK tools v16 release notes and they recommend v16 of the plugin. This is most inconsistent behaviour on the part of the developers.